# Rotate and move line in svg

Tags: css, html, svg, rotation

I want to move a line left and right while rotating around its own center.

With a rect it's extremely easy since you have a x, y and height and width.
Although with a line I can't seem to figure it out.

```
<line id='line' x1='20' y1='100' x2='180' y2='100' stroke-width='2' stroke='black' transform='rotate(410, 100, 100)'></line>
```

I can easily rotate my line by editing the first value of the rotate

Now as soon as I move my line the rotation doesn't work properly anymore and doesn't rotate around its center.

Also moving my object has the urge to go downwards just a little, while it should go straight.

```
this.lineObject.setAttribute("x2", parseInt(this.lineObject.getAttribute("x2")) + step);
this.lineObject.setAttribute("x1", (parseInt(this.lineObject.getAttribute("x2")) - 160)); //160 is the length of the line.
this.lineObject.setAttribute("y2", (parseInt(this.lineObject.getAttribute("y2")) - step));
this.lineObject.setAttribute("y1", (parseInt(this.lineObject.getAttribute("y1")) - step));
```

How can I move my line straight & maintain the ability to rotate around its center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how the second argument of the rotate transform happens to be (x2 + x1) /2 and the third argument is (y1 + y2) / 2 i.e. the centre point of the line.

All you have to do is update the transform attribute when you update the line position.

Comment: You mean the 2 after 410? 100, 100
I tried that but it flew out of screen without me being able to take a good look on what happened

EDIT: Actually, I think I might have made a mistake in my first try on that. I'll try it in a bit

Comment: My move function wasn't accurate, your solution is correct