# SVG line rotate and move

Tags: html, svg, line

I'm trying to move my line while rotating.

The problem is as soon as I move it the line shoots up for some reason. I have put my code in a codepen, uncomment the line `firstLine.Move();` to see what exactly goes wrong.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQrXPo

Comment: How is this different to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565650/rotate-and-move-line-in-svg

Comment: Not a lot, although my source is available there making it easier to see mistakes. I've made some advances towards the end result but the y position is incorrect. Also people stopped responding to it. There hasn't been an correct answer yet

Comment: @RobertLongson How exactly? I've explained my problem, the y position is incorrect since it shoots up

Comment: I undersand that, you've not explained what's wrong with my solution though as you're not using it.

Comment: @RobertLongson My apologies I have explained the problem now. The codepen works fine now as you can see, although running it from my html instead of the codepen it's really laggy.and seems that the size is not caught up with the rotation or something.